# Error with save path. Does not exist or is not supported

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-10.1

The final save raster file errors without message with Does not exist or is not support. But it does exist. If you can find anything wrong with this script I would be very greatfull. I had a vast array of errors with this bit of code. But much of it is already working in other parts of the script.

```
path ="C:/gisdata/india/imagery/"
parentdir ="off"

print "===== using Not isfile and listing folder names only ======="
for fname in os.listdir(path + parentdir):
  if not os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path + parentdir, fname)):
#   pathfolders.append(os.path.join(path, fname))
    dirname.append(fname)

print dirname

#Loop through image directories and list the tif raster files within each and
#process to reflectance values
for dir in dirname:
    print "Setting workspace"
    #Set workspace to current working directory
    env.workspace = path + parentdir + "/" + dir
    print "Workspace set!"



print "Creating local variables for input bands to Dark Pixel Subtraction"
#Local variable = Raster("LE71460402010085ASN00_B1.TIF")
Rt_B1dp = Raster(path + parentdir + "/" + dir + "/" + "Rt_b1.TIF")
Rt_B2dp = Raster(path + parentdir + "/" + dir + "/" + "Rt_b2.TIF")
Rt_B3dp = Raster(path + parentdir + "/" + dir + "/" + "Rt_b3.TIF")
Rt_B4dp = Raster(path + parentdir + "/" + dir + "/" + "Rt_b4.TIF")

sample = "C:/gisdata/india/imagery/sample"
bands = ("Rt_B1.TIF", "Rt_B2.TIF", "Rt_B3.TIF", "Rt_B4.TIF")
dpRasters = (Rt_B1dp, Rt_B2dp, Rt_B3dp, Rt_B4dp)
fieldNames = ("Rt_b1", "Rt_b2", "Rt_b3", "Rt_b4")

for dpRaster in dpRasters:
    for band in bands:
        for fieldName in fieldNames:
            #Sampling raster values using select points from Delhi_dp.shp
            print "Sampling raster values using selected points"
            arcpy.sa.Sample( band,"C:/gisdata/india/imagery/Delhi_dp.shp","sample","NEAREST")

            queryString = '"{0}" IS NOT NULL AND "{0}" > 0'.format(fieldName)
            #Use SearchCursor to query non NULL values for creating a new variable
            with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("sample", (fieldName),queryString) as cursor:
                for row in cursor:
                    dpValue = row[0]

                    print "Starting dpRaster subtraction"
                    if arcpy.Exists(dpRaster):
                        arcpy.Delete_management(dpRaster)
                    print "Subtracting " + str(dpValue) + " from " + str(dpRaster)
                    raster_dp = dpRaster - dpValue
                    print "Saving " + str(dpRaster) + " as image file"
                    raster_dp.save(path + parentdir + "/" + dir + "/" + dpRaster + ".TIF")
                    print str(dpRaster) + " has been created"
```

Comment: Why don't you use os.path.join() for all of your path-building needs? Also, I'm not sure if it's a formatting error, but your indentation doesn't seem correct.

Comment: Thanks, the indentation is correct but they didn't paste into the box very well. Can you elaborate on how I might use os.path.join()? I m a beginner remember :-)

Comment: Try putting an "r" in front of all the path strings, for example, path = r"C:/gisdata/india/imagery/"

Comment: Tried adding r but it still exits without and error message crashing python.

Comment: In your `raster_dp.save()` line, replace what you have in the brackets with `os.path.join(path + parentdir,dir,str(dpRaster) + ".TIF")`. It seems like you might be getting numeric values for dpRaster, in which case you cannot use string concatenation as you currently have it, the number needs to be cast to a string.

Comment: I tried os.path.join() but I get the same error. But now I ve noticed what appears to be happening is the file Rt_b1 appears to be being deleted when it gets to the variable declaration. If I change, and comment out the first declaration then the next file is deleted. I haven't had any problems with this in the past. So I dont know why the files are disappearing. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you determine what line the code is hanging up on?

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be due to single and double slashes.  I might also try defining input and output shapefiles/rasters as local variables.  Try this:

```
path = r"C:/gisdata/india/imagery"
parentdir ="off"

print "===== using Not isfile and listing folder names only ======="
for fname in os.listdir(path + parentdir):
    if not os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path + parentdir, fname)):
    # pathfolders.append(os.path.join(path, fname))
    dirname.append(fname)

print dirname

# Loop through image directories and list the tif raster files within each and
# process to reflectance values
for dir in dirname:
    print "Setting workspace"
#Set workspace to current working directory
env.workspace = path + "//" + parentdir + "//" + dir
print "Workspace set!"

print "Creating local variables for input bands to Dark Pixel Subtraction"
# Local variable = Raster("LE71460402010085ASN00_B1.TIF")
Rt_B1dp = Raster(path + "//" + parentdir + "//" + dir + "//" + "Rt_b1.TIF")
Rt_B2dp = Raster(path + "//" + parentdir + "//" + dir + "//" + "Rt_b2.TIF")
Rt_B3dp = Raster(path + "//" + parentdir + "//" + dir + "//" + "Rt_b3.TIF")
Rt_B4dp = Raster(path + "//" + parentdir + "//" + dir + "//" + "Rt_b4.TIF")

outSample = r"C:/gisdata/india/imagery/sample"
inSample = r"C:/gisdata/india/imagery/Delhi_dp.shp"
bands = ("Rt_B1.TIF", "Rt_B2.TIF", "Rt_B3.TIF", "Rt_B4.TIF")
dpRasters = (Rt_B1dp, Rt_B2dp, Rt_B3dp, Rt_B4dp)
fieldNames = ("Rt_b1", "Rt_b2", "Rt_b3", "Rt_b4")

for dpRaster in dpRasters:
    for band in bands:
        for fieldName in fieldNames:
            # Sampling raster values using select points from Delhi_dp.shp
            print "Sampling raster values using selected points"
            arcpy.sa.Sample(band, inSample, outSample, "NEAREST")

        queryString = '"{0}" IS NOT NULL AND "{0}" > 0'.format(fieldName)
        # Use SearchCursor to query non NULL values for creating a new variable
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("outSample", (fieldName),queryString) as cursor:
            for row in cursor:
                dpValue = row[0]

                print "Starting dpRaster subtraction"
                if arcpy.Exists(dpRaster):
                    arcpy.Delete_management(dpRaster)
                print "Subtracting " + str(dpValue) + " from " + str(dpRaster)
                raster_dp = dpRaster - dpValue
                print "Saving " + str(dpRaster) + " as image file"
                raster_dp.save(path + "//" + parentdir + "//" + dir + "//" + dpRaster + ".TIF")
                print str(dpRaster) + " has been created"
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be double backslashes? At any rate, you're opening up the the output to errors by concatenating paths that way. The `os` module has a function already designed for this...

Comment: @Paul Thanks for the correction, and you are correct about the os module.  I was simply pointing out to Simon that the simplest fix may be adding double backslashes, as he has already pointed out that he lacks an extensive knowledge of python.

Comment: Thanks @Barbarossa, I've tried changing the path to double backslashes but the error persists.